# Can I wire a table lamp with white 0.5 mm sq 3-core copper wire in the UK?

Tags: lamp

Can I wire a table lamp with white 0.5 mm sq 3-core copper wire in the UK?

The wire is labelled 0.5 mm sq 3-core. Is that the cross section area of the copper itself or the cross-section of all the plastic and guff around it? Is this the cross-section of one of the 3 (live/neutral/earth) wires, or the cross-section of them all together?

Are there any charts that tell you the total amps for each cross-section area of copper?

I believe the lamp is 0.25amps. (Its a 60W lamp and I am on the 240V UK British system).

Comment: Is it white outside with coloured wires inside?

Comment: We can't really know. You don't mention what wire it is, is it rated for mains use to begin with, and how you intend to wire the lamp. The wire  or mains cord simply cannot be assessed based on it being 3-core 0.5mm squared, even if it could withstand the current, it can't be used if it is not rated for mains use to begin with. And 3 cores might be weird if the lamp has no connection for earth wire, for example.

Comment: Andrew: There are 3 wires inside, coloured in the normal live/neutral/earth UK colours. We did wiring plugs at school, so I know how to wire a plug. These are all contained in a larger white plastic casing.

Comment: Justme: This was bought from a UK general-public DIY store. It is definitely for mains use.

Comment: The current capability of 0.5 mm² wire is 3 A. A 60 W lamp will take less than 0.3 A, so the wire you have will be fine. Be careful not to nick the inner insulation when removing the white outer sheath. I am not a qualified electrician.

Comment: `Is that the cross section area of the copper itself or the cross-section of all the plastic and guff around it?` ... draw a 1 mm sq circle on a piece of paper and compare to the wire

Comment: A pic of the lamp and its existing wiring would help us. Of course, since you're rewiring it, you could just snip off a section of wire and take it with you to B&Q or any other local store selling wiring and compare it in size there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The marking on the cable sheath is the cross section of each core

In UK it's common practice to pair a plug with a 3A fuse and an appliance lead having 0.5mm^2 wires.

(So that's a "yes", conditional on the use of a 3A fuse in the plug)